# MySQL GROUP columns

Tags: mysql, group-by

I did not find a good solution to my group problem. So here it is:

I'm working in a factory, I'm a planner. I want to see how many parts is ready to ship, but because of our shifts there is an option to get 2 rows.

For example:

```
Item_group I_name Op_desc   Part_number    end_time             Act_end_time
78713/1 TP08001 OP8.1 Marás Q90014045197    2016-10-08 05:35:00 2016-10-07 19:31:00
78713/1 TP08001 OP8.1 Marás Q90014045198    2016-10-10 14:35:00 2016-10-07 14:34:00
78713/1 TP08001 OP8.1 Marás Q90014045199    2016-10-11 05:35:00 2016-10-06 20:32:00
78713/1 TP08001 OP8.1 Marás Q90014045200    2016-10-10 11:35:00 2016-10-07 06:49:00
78713/1 TP08001 OP8.1 Marás Q90014045201    2016-10-10 17:35:00 2016-10-06 01:16:00
78713/1 TP08001 OP8.1 Marás Q90014045202    2016-10-10 14:35:00 2016-10-05 19:54:00
78713/1 TP08001 OP8.1 Marás Q90014045203    2016-10-10 11:35:00 2016-10-07 17:34:00
78713/1 TP08001 OP8.1 Marás Q90014045204    2016-10-07 20:35:00 2016-10-05 20:59:00
78713/1 TP08001 OP8.1 Marás Q90014045205    2016-10-10 17:35:00 2016-10-07 17:12:00
78713/1 TP08001 OP8.1 Marás Q90014045206    2016-09-29 06:36:00 2016-10-06 02:46:00
78713/1 TP08001 OP8.1 Marás Q90014045207    2016-10-10 20:35:00 2016-10-07 02:48:00
78713/1 TP08001 OP8.1 Marás Q90014045208    2016-10-08 06:00:00 2016-10-07 20:07:00
78713/1 TP08001 OP8.1 Marás Q90014045208    2016-10-10 08:35:00 2016-10-07 20:07:00
```

As you see, the last two is the same part (Q90014045208), but because of the shifts it is divided. The actual end time is the same, because this is the date when the manufactoring actually ended. The simple end_time is when the shift is ended. I want to count this as 1, but now there is 2 records so it is not proper.

My code is:

```
SELECT 

   set_id as Item_group
   ,part as Item_name
   ,op_desc as Operation_description
   ,lot as Part_number
   ,end_time as end_time
   ,act_end_time as Act_end_time

FROM
   schexp_hist

WHERE
   set_id like '78713/1' and op_desc='OP8.1 Marás'
```

The "group by lot " is not correct, because if I want to count this then it is not 1, it is 2. I want to create 1 row from these equals.

(I made this query for show my problem, I want to work with these records as source.)

I think a sub query can be good:

```
SELECT
 *
FROM
     schexp_hist

Group by lot
```

But I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Don't include image, better to `desc tables`.

Comment: desc tables is useless, use `show create table xyz`

Comment: I don't know how to do it, I'm new on this site. :/

Comment: Bhai, please embed the result set in the question and also do a show create table and paste the structure in the question @Czera

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GROUP BY **lot** or **Part_number** should work just fine

Comment: Yeah, maybe with a sub query. But in the main? No. I've tried it before. There will be 2 rows too, and thats because the count will se 2 parts, not just 1! 

The results:
78713/1 TP08001 OP8.1 Marás Q90014045207 2016-10-10 20:35:00 2016-10-07 02:48:00 1
78713/1 TP08001 OP8.1 Marás Q90014045208 2016-10-08 06:00:00 2016-10-07 20:07:00 2

Comment: Yeah, maybe with a sub query. But in the main? No. I've tried it before. There will be 2 rows too, and thats because the count will se 2 parts, not just 1! With "count(lot) as QT" The result is: 78713/1 TP08001 OP8.1 Marás Q90014045207 2016-10-10 20:35:00 2016-10-07 02:48:00 Quantity: 1 78713/1 TP08001 OP8.1 Marás Q90014045208 2016-10-08 06:00:00 2016-10-07 20:07:00 Quantity: 2

Comment: @Czera This query will give you a total QT of 12. I hope that helps.
`SELECT COUNT(Part_number) AS QT FROM (
   SELECT Part_number FROM (
     SELECT * FROM schexp_hist 
     WHERE Op_desc='OP8.1 Marás' 
     GROUP BY Part_number
   ) AS T
 ) AS T;`

Comment: Thank you! With this logic, I think WE made it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try group by part_number? And add a count(part_number) field to check whether its 1 or 2 rows